# Should the Teacher badge be encouraged so soon?

Tags: discussion, flags, badges, low-quality-posts

I've seen that the Teacher badge (first answer) is the second recommended badge after Student (first question). It's encouraged by the "Go get it" button.

Why are we encouraging newbies to answer questions *almost* soon as they start using the site?

Isn't it a bit shooting the leg with wrong/misleading/VLQ answers which will be down voted/close/deleted ?

Can this approach be reconsidered?

**EDIT**

Adding regarding @Glorfindel answer, I think how hard is to write a good answer is/can be primary opinion based,unless there's any statistics on this (anyone accept the challenge? ),
But I'm almost sure that on meta sites it's harder to make a positive answer when starting using the site.

Therefore I suggest other badge should encourage after, as [Enthusiast](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/71/enthusiast), which will make the newbies more aware/knowledgeable about specific site Q&A standards (even if they are experts)

[image]

Comment: It is not unusual for a new user's very first interaction with the site to be a positively scored answer. Why would there be an issue with prompting people who haven't already done that to do that for their second interaction?

Comment: @doppelgreener if I start using the site I'm redirect to all questions list which I may have little or none knowledge. I may still don't know / find relevant tags or topics for me

Comment: Well, you could browse that list and find out which tags to watch first...

Comment: Well, the first badge I got after joining the first site (SO) is Teacher on my first answer, followed by Editor, Informed, Supporter, Critic, Commentator (these are the easier badges). Back then, there's no badge recommender like that though, I just searched for a question that I could answer...

Comment: @Somewhat but in photo site you have 5 badges but you don't have answers so it depends, e.g. https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/35498/andrew-t

Comment: @user7294900 hmm, fair point... I can see that the difficulty of getting badges *related to Q or A* depends on the user's knowledge and interest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We're not just encouraging newbies; we also encourage *experts* who have just started browsing a specific Stack Exchange site. Their expertise is (usually) very much welcome.

Also, you don't get the Teacher badge by just posting an answer; it needs to have a score of 1. This works for discouraging users who'd just post a low quality answer in order to get a badge.

Comment: It seems that site assume I'm an expert, no? If I can be a teacher also immediately, no?

Comment: It only assumes the Teacher badge is relatively easy to get; it's just a single post with a single upvote. Easier than asking 4 more questions (on 4 different days), or voting 285 more times (which takes more than a week).

Comment: I think it's primary opinion based,unless there's any statistics, I'm almost sure that on meta sites it's harder to make a positive answer when starting using the site

Comment: For me, it's actually harder to write a good *question* than a good answer (see my network profile for evidence).

Comment: I agree, both are hard (and maybe gets harder each time)